# joomla 1.6 template creation

Tags: templates, joomla

i downloaded and installed joomla 1.6 and i don't like the templates which is comming with joomla, so can you help me to find some program (not artisteer) or tutorial which i can use for creating joomla template. and also i know php, html, css, flash, javascript and i just want to learn basic joomla 1.6 template creation steps.

Answer (score 0):

The [official docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Templates) has a [templates section](http://docs.joomla.org/Template_Development).